# Chord height from circle edge in 3 tangent circles

Tags: geometry

I don't know if this question makes sense, but is there a formulaic way to calculate the height of a chord from a circle's edge in one of the circles from 3 tangent circles?

I have included a diagram to provide detail. Circles C1, C2 and C3 are connected at tangents and have equal radii (in this case 1 mm, but that is only for depiction). Triangle ABC is formed by connecting the centers of these circles. Line LM meets sides AB and AC and is tangential to Circle C1. Line PQ cuts through Circle C1 and triangle ABC and is tangential to both circles C2 and C3.

[Diagram for question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEGgK.jpg)

What is the formula for the distance (x) between lines LM and PQ?

Given that the radii are equal (say, r), the total height of these 3 circles (line RS shown in diagram, which is my objective to calculate) is 4 times the radius minus the distance (x) between lines LM and PQ. In other words,

|RS| = {(4*r) - x}

variable x needs to be converted into a formula based exclusively on radius r so as to solve this equation.

It has been a while since I revisited my high school geometry lessons, so I hope this can be solved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: Apologies. I didn't notice that I posted this question to Stackoverflow. I intended to post it on the Math.stackexchange forum. I'll move it there. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distance A-LM is equal to r  (circle center - tangent)
Distance BC-PQ is equal to r
If we add these distances and subtract distance PQ-LM (x), we'll get height of equilateral triangle ABC (with edge 2*r)

```
r + r  - x = height of ABC = 2 * r * sqrt(3)/ 2
x = r * (2 - sqrt(3))
```

Comment: From where you got `height of ABC = 2 * r * sqrt(3)/ 2`? please add explain to your answer

Comment: The height of an equilateral triangle with side "a" is a * sqrt(3) / 2. In this case, the length of the triangle's sides is 2r.